# networksetup -connectpppoeservice "VPN" does not work anymore on Yosemite

Tags: network, vpn, macos

I have some bash scripts to connect my VPN but since Yosemite was installed they doesn't work anymore.

I tested directly on Terminal with and without **sudo**:

```
networksetup -connectpppoeservice "VPN"
networksetup -disconnectpppoeservice "VPN"
```

but nothing happens

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because including answers directly into the question makes it difficult for future visitors to find the information they are looking for. You can always post an answer to your own question though (and/or ask a new question for the part which still doesn't seem to work as it should).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the some problem and a working solution like this:

**Before Yosemite**

```
networksetup -connectpppoeservice 'MY-VPN-SERVICE-NAME'
```

**On Yosemite**

```
scutil --nc start 'MY-VPN-SERVICE-NAME'
```

I found the hint on Robert's Blog http://roosbertl.blogspot.de/2014/10/auto-connect-osx-yosemite-ipsec-vpn-on.html

Works für IPSec and PPTP

Comment: For some reason, it seems to also be necessary to include `--secret sharedsecret` on the command line.

Answer (score -1):

I set my Wifi to DHCP instead of static IP, then it worked for me.