# `scutil --nc start` not connecting PPPT VPN - OS X 10.11

Tags: terminal, network, command-line, vpn

From the answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151126/networksetup-connectpppoeservice-vpn-does-not-work-anymore-on-yosemite/158040#158040) I have tried `scutil --nc start 'us.justfreevpn.com'` to connect a PPPT VPN, but all I get is the following popup:

[image: popup]

Frustratingly, if I manually start the connection from the menubar, I can then stop it using `scutil --nc stop 'us.justfreevpn.com'`

`scutil --nc list` gives the following:

```
Available network connection services in the current set (*=enabled):
* (Disconnected)   16DB05C1-0843-447F-9EA0-AD43139270AF PPP --> PPTP       "us.justfreevpn.com"             [PPP:PPTP]
```

And `scutil --nc show 'us.justfreevpn.com'` this:

```
* (Disconnected)   16DB05C1-0843-447F-9EA0-AD43139270AF PPP --> PPTP       "us.justfreevpn.com"             [PPP:PPTP]
PPP <dictionary> {
  ACSPEnabled : 1
  CCPEnabled : 1
  CommDisplayTerminalWindow : 0
  CommRedialCount : 1
  CommRedialEnabled : 0
  CommRedialInterval : 5
  CommUseTerminalScript : 0
  DialOnDemand : 0
  DisconnectOnFastUserSwitch : 1
  DisconnectOnIdle : 0
  DisconnectOnIdleTimer : 600
  DisconnectOnLogout : 1
  DisconnectOnSleep : 0
  IPCPCompressionVJ : 0
  IdleReminder : 0
  IdleReminderTimer : 1800
  LCPEchoEnabled : 1
  LCPEchoFailure : 15
  LCPEchoInterval : 20
  Logfile : /var/log/ppp.log
  VerboseLogging : 0
}
```

The log just shows the following:

```
Tue Feb 23 10:18:44 2016 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Tue Feb 23 10:18:44 2016 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
```

And last exit code is 0:

```
$ echo $?
0
```

What am I doing wrong?

OS X 10.11.3

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Having similar issue

Comment: Sadly not @Nath

Answer (score 1):

Was running into same issue. Ended up going the AppleScript route:

```
tell application "System Events"
        tell current location of network preferences
                set VPN to service "UniVPN" -- your VPN name here
                if exists VPN then connect VPN
                repeat while (current configuration of VPN is not connected)
                    delay 1
                end repeat
        end tell
end tell
```

(From https://superuser.com/a/358663/17760)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on macOS 10.12.6
Root cause was, that I also changed the configuration name of the VPN

After removing the old VPN and creating a VPN with another name and configuration "Default",  it works with both the command scutil and networksetup
[image]